# circulating an image with jquery around a circle path

Tags: jquery, image, geometry

how i can circulate an image with jquery around  a **circle path** ?
please check the picture. i want something like this.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/I74mZ.png
red is moving on path
tanks  a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [JQuery.path](http://weepy.github.com/jquery.path/).